# Reactjs is there any shortcut for multiple element type declaration

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings, tsx

I am getting values from the form. I am using `tsx` for my project. But I am much unhappy to use a long element type like this:

```
handleChange = (e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement> | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>, id: string ) =>{
        e.preventDefault();
        const {value} = e.target;
        this.setState((prev) => ({fields: {...this.state.fields, [id]:value}}));
        console.log(id, this.state.fields);
    }
```

where the `e` ( event ) has:

`e:React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement> | React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>`

such a long type declaration. is there any way to shorten this? or any other type help to take care of all form elements?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess you could use `alias` but you have to declare the long type names somewhere else so I guess that is not you are looking for

Comment: @SinanYaman - yes you are correct.

Comment: It's not perfect but maybe [this](https://www.carlrippon.com/React-event-handlers-with-typescript/) can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could do this:

```
handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement>, id: string ) =>{
```

Which is definitely a bit more concise. Or as was mentioned, you could simply alias your type declaration with `type`:

```
type FormChangeEvent = React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLSelectElement>;

// ...

handleChange = (e: FormChangeEvent, id: string ) =>{
```

But aside from that, as far as I'm aware there is no existing type alias that encompasses the exact change events you're looking for. Nor, really, *should* there be, because those elements have different type definitions for a reason, and `e.target` should reflect them accordingly.

Depending on your use case, you could just define a simple, limited type for the event that gives you only the type info you actually need. Doing such a thing is fairly common in my experience, for the exact reason you have run into - sometimes concision and simplicity is more valuable than kitchen sink type completionism.

```
handleChange = (e: { target: { value: string}; preventDefault: () => {} }, id: string ) =>{
```

Edit: another thing you can do here is simply type `e` as `any`. If you know what you're doing and are careful, this is fairly safe - or, at least, no more dangerous than the days before we had TypeScript.

```
handleChange = (e: any, id: string ) =>{
```

Comment: I tried your last approach, getting an error as `Property 'preventDefault' does not exist on type '{ target: { value: string; }; }'`

Comment: @user2024080 Good catch, if you want that property too you can add it like so: `handleChange = (e: { target: { value: string}; preventDefault: () => {} }, id: string ) =>{
`